# getting error when saving Excel file in Azure Function app temp folder

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function app written in NodeJS that generates an Excel file and emails it as an attachment.

I'm using npm package ExcelJS to create the Excel file and npm package NodeMailer to send the file as an attachment.

Here is my Azure Function index.js:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions";
import * as azdev from "azure-devops-node-api";
import * as witif from "azure-devops-node-api/interfaces/WorkItemTrackingInterfaces";
import * as witapi from "azure-devops-node-api/WorkItemTrackingApi"

const timerTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, myTimer: any): Promise<void> {
    let orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization name}"
    let token = process.env["DEVOPS_TOKEN"] // token gets inserted during runtime
    let authHandler = azdev.getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(token); 
    let connection = new azdev.WebApi(orgUrl, authHandler);
    const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
    const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
    const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

    const queryId = "....8798987"; // work item query id from Azure Boards
    const wit: witapi.IWorkItemTrackingApi = await connection.getWorkItemTrackingApi();
    const result = await wit.queryById(queryId);

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new Error("Result was null.");
    }

    // generate Excel file
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    workbook.creator = 'Me';
    workbook.lastModifiedBy = 'Me';
    workbook.created = new Date();
    const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Query Results');

    let colNames: string[] = [];
    let colRefNames: string[] = [];
    let queryItems = [];
    let fields: string[] = []

    for (let col of result.columns) {
        colNames.push(col.name);
        colRefNames.push(col.referenceName);
    }
    sheet.columns = colNames;

    for (let item of result.workItems) {
       queryItems.push(await wit.getWorkItem(item.id, colRefNames) )
    }

    for (let q of queryItems) {
        for (let f of Object.keys(q.fields)) {
            if (f == 'System.AssignedTo') {
                sheet.addRow(q.fields[f].displayName)
            } else {
                sheet.addRow(q.fields[f])
            }
        }
    } 
    const currentdate = DateTime.now().toFormat('MM-dd-yy');
    context.log('creating Excel file');
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./%TMP%/workitemquery_' + currentdate + '.xlsx').then(() => {
        context.log('saved');
    }).catch((err) => {
        context.log('err', err);
    })

    // Send the email
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "{SMTP Server IP address}",
        port: 50025,
        secure: false,
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        ...
        attachments: [
            filename: 'workitemquery_' + currentdate + '.xlsx',
            path: './%TMP%/workitemquery_' + currentdate + '.xlsx'
        ]
    }

    context.log('Sending email');
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({mailOptions, function(error, info) {
            if (error) {
                context.log("sent mail error: " +error.message);
            }
            context.log(info.response);
        }
    });       
};

export default timerTrigger;
```

When I run the Function app, it fails during the workbook.xlsx.writeFile function and gives this error:

```
err [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\%TMP%\workitemquery_11-20-22.xlsx'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\%TMP%\\workitemquery_11-20-22.xlsx'
}
```

I'm trying to save the file to the Function app's temp folder which is %TMP%, but it's saving in the wrong place. How do I save the Excel file in the right folder so the sendMail function can find it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem. Part of the problem was the temp folder didn't exist in the Azure Function storage account. I created this folder path `C:\local\Temp`.
The second part was I had to hard code the file path using Windows format, like this:

```
await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('C:\\local\\Temp\\workitemquery_' + currentdate + '.xlsx')

attachments: [
            {
                filename: 'ukfastserverquery_' + currentdate + '.xlsx',
                path: 'C:\\local\\Temp\\workitemquery_' + currentdate + '.xlsx'
            }
        ]
```